# WSO2: Carbon application server & tomcat manager application

Tags: tomcat, wso2

WSO2 Application server is based on Tomcat. Why is the manager application removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All WSO2 Servers have a embedded tomcat running inside them. I guess, WSO2AS provides better management console for managing web application. I am not sure about the exact reason to remove it..But if you want you can copy war file in to "repository/deployment/server/webapps" or upload from management console UI.

Comment: Maybe WSO2 provides better management, but Tomcat supplies the manager application out-of-the-box. Why is it removed? We have products to monitor our middleware, these tools expects the manager application. As WSO2 is open source, based on Tomcat, I was expecting this application.

Comment: Then it is easy...  just deploy this war file in to WSO2As... :)  I guess there is nothing to be worried.